# Is it safe to share Firefox cert8.db key3.db files?

Tags: firefox

I've added custom CA root certificate for my Firefox. Can I safely share `cert8.db` and `key3.db` files with other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cert8.db` shouldn't be a problem - unless it contains (unlikely) client-side certificates that acts as login credentials, or it has already accepted other untrustworthy CA's.

`key3.db` is more problematic - it contains keys to unlock the login/username/site data in `logins.json`.  However you may have protected those keys with a master password that makes passing that data a bit pointless (except,perhaps, to determined crackers).

If you don't have a master password then **beware** if you export your entire profile because that would definitely expose all your private login/username/site data.